# Submit button is not being displayed on Ipad

Tags: html, forms, ipad, submit

I have done a simple html form, and my client says she doesn't see the submit button. I tried making a basic html document with the form but it happens the same. The rest of the fields are ok.
On PC evereything is fine.
Thanks!

This the code:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">

<label for="adress">Address</label>
<input type="text" name="address" id="adress" ><br>

<label for="city">City</label>
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" ><br>

<label for="state">State</label>
<input type="text" name="state" id="state" ><br>

<label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
<input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" ><br>

<label for="telefono">Ph</label>
<input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" ><br>

<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email">

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment">
Comment here
</textarea>

<button type="submit" > Submit </button>

</form>
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it changing

```
<button type="submit" > Submit </button>
```

By

```
<input type="submit">
```